# Google reCAPTCHA: How many tries of the puzzle does user get?

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

Got a request with a list of questions from Business to investigate the possibility of integration [Google reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/) with our Site and one of the questions is:

- How many tries of the puzzle does user get?

and the second one:

- What happens if the user fails the puzzle as many times as it is allowed to attempt?

I spend a few hours to find the proper answers to the questions above and unfortunately, I didn't get success. No required information on official site, Google Search did not help as well.

Comment: a.k.a. how much annoying the eff out of our customers you think we can get away with ... :-) Seriously: Find something else, if you value your customers _at all_.

Comment: are you asking about the [tag:invisible-recaptcha] specifically as your tag indicates?

Comment: @ashleedawg, question about invisible-recaptcha and just recaptcha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google reCaptchas do not have a default "unsuccessful attempt limit" and I'm not aware of any option set one up.  Captchas are not intended to turn away humans (or hackers), regardless of how many tries it take.

Captchas (an acronym for *"**C**ompletely **A**utomated **P**ublic **T**uring test to tell **C**omputers and **H**umans **A**part"*) are unnecessary unless your site is at risk of excessive scraping or automated spam.

[Invisible Captcha's](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) seem to be the preferred choice nowadays, to reduce user annoyance with the security feature.

Here are links to:

- [Google's reCaptcha demo](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo)
- [Google's Invisible reCaptcha demo](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo?invisible=true)
- [FunCaptcha Verification by Puzzle](https://www.funcaptcha.com/demo/)
- [21 Free CAPTCHA Sources](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/22/21-free-captcha-sources/)